# Resource not found error while running Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm getting the error below while running Emulator, it's a project imported from Eclipse. I searched the project for below style commands but did not find them. I also tried emulators from API 22 till 28, but still the same.

> Android resource linking failed
>   error: resource
>   android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
>   error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
>   error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse not found.
>   error: resource android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored not found.
>   error: failed linking references.